# NDSolve in NIntegrate function, numerical values as a symbolic variables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to implement the following iterative scheme $g_{n+1}=g_n-\int_0^t\Phi(g_n) dt$, where $g_n$ is a source term in a PDE and $\Phi$ is the solution of an adjoit problem associated to the PDE which use the solution of the PDE as final data. to this aim we need many steps :

> 0) Take $g_0=0$.
>
> 1) Solve the PDE to obtain the solution $u(t,x,g_n)$.
>
> 2) Solve the adjoint PDE to obtain $\Phi(t,x,g_n)$.
>
> 3) Calculate $g_{n+1}(x)=g_n(x)-\int_0^t\Phi(t,x,g_n) dt$, and go to 1).

I tried this one

```
nsol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x] + #, u[0, x] == 1, 
u[t, 0] == u[t, 1] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}] &; (* Solve the pde with source # *)

nasol = NDSolve[{D[v[t, x], t] == -D[v[t, x], x, x], 
 v[1, x] == First[u[1, x] /. nsol[#]] - umes[x], 
 v[t, 0] == v[t, 1] == -0.05}, v, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}] &; (* Solve the adjont problem *)

Phi := NIntegrate[Evaluate[First[v[t, #2] /. nasol[#1[x]]]], {t, 0, 1}]&;
(* Calculate the integral in step 3). Here is the problem !!*)

g[0][x_] := 0;
umes[x_] := First[u[1, x] /. nsol[g[0][x]]] + 0.05;
g[n_Integer?Positive][x_] := g[n - 1][x] - Phi[g[n - 1], x];(* iteration *)
```

Now when I test the program, it seems to work in a good way

```
In[68]:= Phi[g[0], 0.1]
Out[68]= -0.05
In[70]:= g[1][0.1]
Out[70]= 0.05
```

To turn the loop for calculating the function $g_2$ we need to put $g_1$ in step 1) and here is the problem : The functions `Phi[g[1],x]` is just a numerical function and not working for symbolic variable $x$ because of the `NIntegrate`. Hence, the same problem for `g[1][x]`.

Here is the Mathematica error

```
In[80]:= Phi[g[0], x]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand <<1>> has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,0.0547861}}.

I tried to use `NumericQ` for the variables but still not working. Also, I don't get how to close the loop using stopping condition like `Norm[Phi(g[n][x],x]]<10^{-6}`.

Finally, I notice that I'm new to Mathematica. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Here is an incorrect problem for a parabolic equation for `v[t,x]`. What do you want to get as a result?

Comment: Why it is incorrect ? This is an adjoint equation (backward) associated to the first one. It is well-known in the literature.

Comment: In theory, such equations can be investigated, but in numerical methods this is a typical example of an ill-posed problem.

Comment: I think it's well-posed one even in numerical methods because it is just a resulting equation for the first one using transformation $t'=T-t$. Moreover, I tested some examples and It works. I think you mean this one $v_t -\Delta v=0$ (- instead of +), $v(T,x)=0$ which is ill-posed theoretically.

Comment: If $t'=T-t$ then it should be `{t,0,1}->{t',1,0}`.

Comment: @Alex, Yes, you are right. Then we should use retrograde time. I don't know how to solve such backward equation. On the other hand, the main problem is : how to tell to Mathematica to use the function `Phi` with symbolic variable and then replace the numerical function $g[1][x]$ in NDsolve. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm a bit confused with the elimination of calculation back, It should be  `t'->1-t` or `t'->-t` ?, because you choose the second while I think the first is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I show an algorithm for solving such problems. Calculation back is eliminated by replacing `t'->-t, {-1,0}->{0,1}`:

```
g[0][x_] := .01*x; n = 5;

Do[nsol[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x] + g[i - 1][x], 
    u[0, x] == 1, u[t, 0] == 1, u[t, 1] == 1}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}];
 nasol[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{D[v[t, x], t] == D[v[t, x], x, x], 
    v[0, x] == nsol[i][1, x] - nsol[1][1, x] - .05, v[t, 0] == -.05, 
    v[t, 1] == -0.05}, v, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}];
 g[i] = Interpolation[
   Table[{x, g[i - 1][x] - NIntegrate[nasol[i][t, x], {t, 0, 1}]}, {x,
      0, 1, .1}]];, {i, 1, n}]



 {Plot[Evaluate[Table[g[i][x], {i, 0, n}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "g"}], 
 Plot3D[nsol[n][t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "nsol[n]"], 
 Plot3D[nasol[n][t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "nasol[n]", PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

In the case of 2D +1, we use summation instead of the `NIntegrate[]`. In this example `npoints=8`.

```
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`
gl[npoints_] := 
 Block[{npo = npoints}, {pts, w} = 
   Transpose[GaussianQuadratureWeights[npo, 0, 1]]; {w, pts, npo}]

f[x_, y_] := 1; (* The exact source term to be constructed *)
Plot3D[f[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Source term f(x,y)", PlotLegends -> Automatic]

nsoleq = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
     D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + f[x, y], 
    u[0, x, y] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, 0, y] == 0, 
    u[t, x, 1] == 0, u[t, 1, y] == 0}, 
   u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
    1}]; (* nsoleq[1,x,y] is the observation used in construction of \
the source term *)
Plot3D[nsoleq[1, x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}, 
 PlotLabel -> "t=1", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
g[0][x_, y_] := 0.;  (* Initialization of the iteration *)



With[{np0 = 16, np1 = .05, n = 40}, 
 Do[nsol[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
      D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + g[i - 1][x, y], 
     u[0, x, y] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, 0, y] == 0, 
     u[t, x, 1] == 0, u[t, 1, y] == 0}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];

  nasol[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{D[v[t, x, y], t] == 
      D[v[t, x, y], x, x] + D[v[t, x, y], y, y], 
     v[0, x, y] == nsol[i][1, x, y] - nsoleq[1, x, y], 
     v[t, x, 0] == 0, v[t, 0, y] == 0, v[t, x, 1] == 0, 
     v[t, 1, y] == 0}, v, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 5*15 + 1, "MaxPoints" -> 5*15 + 1, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic}}];
  pp = Interpolation[
    Chop[Flatten[
      Table[{{x, y}, 
        Sum[nasol[i][gl[np0][[2]][[j]], x, y]*gl[np0][[1]][[j]], {j, 
          1, np0}]}, {x, 0, 1, np1}, {y, 0, 1, np1}], 1]]];
  p[i][x_, y_] := pp[x, y] + 0.000001*g[i - 1][x, y];
  nsol1[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
      D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + p[i][x, y], 
     u[0, x, y] == 0, u[t, x, 0] == 0, u[t, 0, y] == 0, 
     u[t, x, 1] == 0, u[t, 1, y] == 0}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]; 
  a[i] = (NIntegrate[
      p[i][x, y]^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
       1}])/(NIntegrate[(nsol1[i][1, x, y])^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]);
  g[i] = Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, g[i - 1][x, y] - a[i]*(p[i][x, y])}, {x, 0,
        1, np1}, {y, 0, 1, np1}], 1]]; npr = i; 
  If[Abs[g[i][.5, .5] - g[i - 1][.5, .5]] <= 10^-5, Break[]], {i, 1, 
   n}]]
{Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "Exact Source"], 
 Plot3D[g[n][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Constructed Source", PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: great !! Thank you for your help. Now I can tackle my complicated problem. I think It's `t'->1-t` and `{1,0}->{0,1}`.

Comment: @S.Cho You're welcome!

Comment: Hello @Alex. I adapted the algorithm you proposed to construct a source term in a pde. It works nice and gives faster results. After this I adopted the algorithm to construct 2D function in 2D heat equation, and in a given step I need to devide by some parameter calculated from `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Here I have many problems that I can't solve after long attempts. Mainly I have problem in this step and the convergence is to late because of this error. Could you take a look on my code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @S.Cho What code do you want to debug?

Comment: Here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykkw9itp0ljvapb/iteration2D.nb?dl=0

Comment: There is a typo with `p[i]`, this function must be defined for each pair `{x,y}` using `Interpolation[Chop[Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, NIntegrate[nasol[i][t, x, y], {t, 0, 1}]}, {x, 0,      1, .1}, {y, 0, 1, .1}], 1]]]`

Comment: After modification the program runs and take a long time for one iteration and returns this :
`NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option`

Comment: I think the problem comes when using `NIntegrate` inside `Interpolation` wich take a long time.

Comment: You can replace the integral with a quadrature formula.

Comment: Really I don't understand the problem. How to use a quadrature formula.

Comment: Can I place the debugged code here?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: @S.Cho See update to my post.

Comment: Thank you !, I will test it to better understand it.

Comment: Unfortunately the algorithm is very slow (increasing the number of iterations) and I don't know if it converges or no. In 1-D case for such simple function it converges in 3 or 5 iterations.

Comment: It must be investigated. I updated the code to conveniently change the parameters.